# Is there any way to interact with Brother Guano at the Temple of Titan? Brute force skill is not available

Tags: wasteland-2

My party entered the temple of Titan, got shot at by some monks, shot them dead, and defused some alarms.  The first interesting thing we found was a guy who makes a "muffled shouting" noise.  Presumably he is in a straitjacket.

I tried "converse" and I couldn't interact.

Recalling that sometimes "Surgery" was necessary to free people trapped by vines, I tried surgery and couldn't do it.  I tried lockpick and it said "not a valid target."

I don't have any party members with "brute force" skill, or I would try that.

Possibly there is no way to interact with this character at this time.  (I wonder why the game didn't give some clues as to why I can't interact.)  Should I continue trying to interact, should I explore the rest of the temple first, or should I just leave the temple, wander away, and forget about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click on the intercom built into the wall, when he's still contained.  I have no idea what happens if you break into his cell, maybe that still works.